# Can't find my ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have been using gems fine. I use compass watch to map changes to my scss files to css files.

I hadn't used it for a week. I tried doing compass watch, and now its telling me compass isn't installed. I did a gem list command and I only have six gems locally now. I looked in my ruby gems folder in my install and All my gems are there.

Any idea what could be going on? Do I uninstall ruby and do it all over again?

Comment: Run `gem env` and copy/paste the output into your question by editing it. Be sure to format it so it's readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the details about your Ruby environment by typing:

```
gem env
```

In the output look for `- GEM PATHS:` to know exactly where your gems are stored. You can have more than one gemset.

Comment: ok, thanks. I was able to use that to verify I do in fact have two gemsets. Not sure how that happened. I certainly haven't installed a new one lately and was able to use compass and other utilities without a problem. Is it normal in this case for it to suddenly just start acting up? And if so, should I just delete one of them?

What's the best process for deleting gemsets?

Comment: @Sage You can edit your `~/.bashrc` file to assign a default gemset. Add this: `export GEM_PATH=/home/myown` to your bashrc. If already present, delete/comment the one you dont want to load. Then reload the bashrc file using: `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Both of my gemsets are 1.9.1. But now it seems to be working fine. I didn't do anything to change it either. I'll keep your advice in mind for future reference. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of a version manager, like [RVM](https://rvm.io/), because if so, your gems might be in a different gemset.

You could run the following command to check the gemset:

```
rvm gemset list
```